# Can't throw exception from inside symfony security Voters

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I am using custom symfony voters and using unanimous strategy.  Access decision manager loops over voters and isGranted return boolean.

We can't throw exception from inside Voter to know why the access was denied. I want to know which voters has denied access and why so that I can show appropriate  messages to user to take action e.g. to upgrade to perticular subscription. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Why you can't throw exception from voter?

Comment: Because of the way access decision manager strategies work. if we throw exception, it won't go to the next voter. Access decision manager loops over voters and decide on the basis of affirmative, consensus and unanimous.

Comment: So, just log to file what you want. (or var_dump, or echo...)

Comment: i don't want to log. I want to throw to top most layer so that I can display message to user

Comment: Inject session and add flashbag notices.

Comment: we dont have sessions, we use oauth. Anyways I am overriding Access decision manager.

Answer (score 0):

A good algorithm could be:

- Throw an exception inside the voter
- Catch it into Manager, store it into an Array or an Object and continue
- After the chain (loop) is finished, check if Manager "collected" some exception and behave accordingly